# How to overlay an image on camera view for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, overlay, augmented-reality

I am new to iphone development, and I want to make an application that will use the camera view as the background. Then I would like to put certain image overlays over the camera view.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cameraOverlayView` property when using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. This property is not available when using other sourceTypes though.

```
[picker setCameraOverlayView: someTransparentView];
```